# cannot use the box created with packer post-processor vagrant

Tags: vagrant, packer

I followed the tutorial on packer.io to create a vagrant box from an amazon-ebs backed instance : https://www.packer.io/intro.

Only issue, the created .box file only contains a Vagrantfile and metadata.json, but I cannot find out how to use this in vagrant with virtualbox since all other boxes I have seen (among them hashcorp/precise32) have a .vmdk and .ovf file and mine doesn't !! Anyone has followed the tutorial and can advise me ? Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I think I found out : the vagrant box created for post-processing is meant to be used with the vagrant-aws plugin, not with virtualbox.
The provider is then "aws" and not "virtualbox", hence why I do not get the .vmdk and .ovf files. The aws-plugin is only to boot and provision EC2 instances, where as what I wanted to do was to "capture" the Amazon minimal linux interface in order to test it locally (cannot find a bloody iso file for it).
I must then surrender, packer.io was my last hope : I cannot find a way to set-up a VM with the minimal amazon linux image running...